# MOSFET and BJT Gain Comparision

Tags: mosfet, bjt

Which transistor has higher gain: BJT or MOSFET and why?

Also how can we compare these two gains as BJT is current controlled current source with input current Ib and output current Ic whereas MOSFET is a voltage controlled current source with input a voltage Vg and output a current Id.

Comment: This question sounds pretty useless and barely meaningful without an application in mind.

Comment: Then just don't comment....This was asked to me in Texas Instruments interview....The guy who was taking my interview has 15 years of experience.

Comment: It's like asking "why 2+2 is 5" and telling someone saying that it is wrong not to comment. There is *no* gain of MOSFET. Gain is a unitless measure resulting from division of output by input expressed in the same units. What is the input and output of MOSFET?

Comment: What was your interview answer and what did the TI guy say?

Comment: Hmm, 15 years of experience you say. Then he should have phrased his question in a better way. As mentioned, "gain" is a property of a **circuit**, not of a device. A MOSFET circuit can have **infinite** power gain but for the same current the gm of a BJT is higher than the gm of a MOSFET. So the question is unanswerable without making some additional constraints.

Comment: Obviously an interview question designed to filter out those who have absolutely no idea what they're talking about.

Comment: Before this gets closed can you let me know what was your interview answer and what did the TI guy say.

Comment: BJTs give you a better gain because it doesn't depend on a voltage bias like a MOSFET does. You can also thank the Miller Effect for a MOSFET for being a worse choice for the gain. A lot of modern amplifiers use BJTs nowadays.

Comment: Go here for a pretty good overview worth reading: https://global.oup.com/us/companion.websites/fdscontent/uscompanion/us/static/companion.websites/9780199339136/Appendices/Appendix_G.pdf It is long and detailed and neatly contrasts the two.

Comment: I suspect the interviewer was more interested in how you handled the question.

Comment: This is a pointless question.  What's better, 3 tomatos or 7 marbles?

Comment: I was clueless...I didn't say anything...Then he asked me the next difference between BJT and MOSFET.

Comment: @KingDuken But a MOSFET has infinite power gain so how can a BJT beat that ? Your claim that modern amps use BJTs is nonsense. Your modern smartphone is crammed with MOSFET amplifiers. BJTs are only used in niche applications.

Answer (score 4):

If this is an interview question, I would believe it to be intentionally tricky, most likely the aim is to see what questions you will ask, which will tell a lot about how you think and what you really know.

The first question would be to define "gain", is it current gain, voltage gain, power gain? And since gain is a property of the circuit, this would lead to "in what circuit configuration?" (common collector or common emitter, etc).

For example, FETs do have current gain, which is Id/Ig. At DC it is close to infinity, but as frequency increases, gate current due to internal capacitance rises, thus current gain depends on frequency. It is simply the FET's transconductance at its current bias point divided by its input impedance (Cgs, plus other capacitances including Miller effect). BJT's current gain also depends on frequency, as some of the base current will be wasted on internal capacitances, but the effect is less visible since base voltage swing is much lower.

Comment: Yes, these **tricky** questions rarely have textbook answers. The interviewers interest is on the "why", not "which one has more gain". A tricky prof might ask a test question with superfluous specs, or trickier: a critical spec left out. Answers that provide a reasonable missing spec win.

Comment: It's an interview question...asked in TI. He asked me when to use Mosfet and when to use BJT. I told him BJT gain is more compared to MOSFET. Then he asked me to define gain. Then asked this question

Comment: *I told him BJT gain is more compared to MOSFET* I would then have asked **why** and **when**. I can design a circuit where the MOSFET has more gain so there. If you would have answered that the MOSFET has the higher gain then I would have replied that I can design a circuit where the BJT would have more gain. See, it's a trick question, there is no single truth. The answer is: **It depends** and then you should elaborate on what it depends.

Comment: That's why I may be rejected.

Comment: Yeah, well, when I came straight from University I might have fallen into the same trap. It takes time and experience to see all the relations in analog design. For me what would count more is your ability to quickly understand such relations after I've explained them to you. Most companies prefer to hire experienced designers but these are scarce. If TI is smart they'd judge you on your **potential** and not what you know now. They have the knowledge. It is up to you learn from them.

Comment: It's obvious now what is going on.  You made a bad statement about BJT gain being higher than MOSFET gain.  He first tried to get you to see this by making you think what "gain" really meant in this context.  When you flunked that too, he asked you the question you quoted.  This was either to have a laugh himself at your expense, to be a little sarcastic and see if you finally noticed your blunder, or to see how far you'd go to hang yourself.  Of course that was only for his entertainment.  You had already proven to be unsuitable and trying to BS your way thru the interview.

Answer (score -1):

MOSFETS are adjustable in the transconductance, by altering width and channel_length (distance from source to drain). For older MOSFETS, the drain current also has a linear improvement on transconductance, with scale factors of doping and W/L.

Bipolars do not allow that adjustability.

Comment: But bipolars always have a higher gm for a given current. *For older MOSFETS, the drain current also has a linear improvement on transconductance*. That's nonsense, look up the formula for gm as a function of Id in saturation mode. gm depends on the square root of Id. So not linear, far from it. For a bipolar it is linear.

Comment: Id = K/2 * W/L * Vgs^2, now take the derivative, and dId/dVgs is a linear function

Comment: Sure, gm is a linear function for a **fixed** Id, but I'm talking about what **gm** you get when choosing a different **Id**. Your derivative **neglects** the fact that the DC value of Vgs changes when the DC value of Id is changed. See end of this lecture: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-012-microelectronic-devices-and-circuits-fall-2005/lecture-notes/lec11.pdf  gm scales with SQRT(W/L * Id).